# How can I expand the row only when that row was clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have this materia-ui table. Every time I'll click the button to expand the row1, it will also expand the second row. How can I fix this where only that specific row will expand?

```
<Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow hover>
      <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Created Date</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
  {data &&
   data((index) => (
    <TableRow hover>
      <TableCell>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="expand row"
          size="small"
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          >
          {open ? (
            <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
          ) : (
            <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
          )}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {index.title}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {new Date(
            index.createdDate.seconds * 1000
          ).toDateString()}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            {index.text}
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
     ))}
   </TableBody>
 </Table>
```

Comment: please set ```key``` for TableRow

Comment: @hamedhossani i tried this `{announcement &&
                announcement.map((index, i) => (
                  <TableRow key={i}>` but it did not work. All rows will expand even if I'll click just one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `TableRow` in a component

```
const Row = ({item}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return <TableRow>...</TableRow>
}

<TableBody>
  {data.map((item, index) => (
    <Row key={index} item={item} />
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

[image: Edit table-collapse]

Comment: I tried putting that on my `TableRow` and it does not work

Comment: @RavenousRed Edited my answer.