# In materia-ui table. When I click the button to expand the row, it expands all rows. How can i make only selected row will expand?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

Row Click event expands all rows in the data table to display inner data of all rows

Expand button click expands all rows instead of selected row. Every time I'll click the button to expand the row1, it will also expand the second row. How can I fix this where only that specific row will expand?

```html
<Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow hover>
      <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Created Date</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
  {data &&
   data((index) => (
    <TableRow hover>
      <TableCell>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="expand row"
          size="small"
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          >
          {open ? (
            <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
          ) : (
            <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
          )}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {index.title}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {new Date(
            index.createdDate.seconds * 1000
          ).toDateString()}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            {index.text}
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
     ))}
   </TableBody>
 </Table>
```

Comment: Similar question was asked in the below thread but no solution provided:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904285/how-can-i-expand-the-row-only-when-that-row-was-clicked

Comment: It's likely beause you have only one state `open` that applies to all rows. You probably need a state array, with one element for each row. But your sample does not have enough code to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you @tromgy, I was able to make it working by adding index to onClick event along with open argument and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the index to open function and allow only selected row expansion. It works as expected and below is my modified code

```html
<Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow hover>
      <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Created Date</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
  {data &&
   data((index) => (
    <TableRow hover>
      <TableCell>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="expand row"
          size="small"
          onClick={() => setOpen(open === index ? -1 : index)}
          >
          {open == index ? (
            <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
          ) : (
            <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
          )}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {index.title}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {new Date(
            index.createdDate.seconds * 1000
          ).toDateString()}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open == index} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            {index.text}
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
     ))}
   </TableBody>
 </Table>
```